# Choosing proper database in AWS when all items must be read from the table

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, architecture, amazon-dynamodb

I have an AWS application where DynamoDB is used for most data storage and it works well for most cases. I would like to ask you about one particular case where I feel DynamoDB might not be the best option.

There is a simple table with customers. Each customer can collect virtual coins so each customer has a *balance* attribute. The *balance* is managed by 3rd party service keeping up-to-date value and the *balance* attribute in my table is just a cached version of it. The 3rd party service requires its own id of the customer as an input so customers table contains also this *externalId* attribute which is used to query the balance.

I need to run the following process once per day:

1. Update the *balance* attribute for all customers in a database.
2. Find all customers with the *balance* greater than some specified constant value. They need to be sorted by the *balance*.
3. Perform some processing for all of the customers - the processing must be performed in proper order - starting from the customer with the greatest *balance* in descending order (by *balance*).

**Question**: which database is the most suitable one for this use case?

My analysis:

In terms of costs it looks to be quite similar, i.e. paying for Compute Units in case of DynamoDB vs paying for hours of micro instances in case of RDS. Not sure though if micro RDS instance is enough for this purpose - I'm going to check it but I guess it should be enough.

In terms of performance - I'm not sure here. It's something I will need to check but wanted to ask you here beforehand. Some analysis from my side:

- It involves two scan operations in the case of DynamoDB which
  looks like something I really don't want to have. The first scan can be limited to *externalId* attribute, then balances are queried from 3rd party service and updated in the table. The second scan requires a range key defined for *balance* attribute to return customers sorted by the *balance*.
- I'm not convinced that any kind of indexes can help here. Basically, there won't be too many read operations of the *balance* - sometimes it will need to be queried for a single customer using its primary key. The number of reads won't be much greater than number of writes so indexes may slow the process down.

Additional assumptions in case they matter:

1. There are ca. 500 000 customers in the database, the average size of a single customer is 200 bytes. So the total size of the customers in the database is 100 MB.
2. I need to repeat step 1 from the above procedure (update the *balance* of all customers) several times during the day (ca. 20-30 times per day) but the necessity to retrieve sorted data is only once per day.
3. There is only one application (and one instance of the application) performing the above procedure. Besides that, I need to handle simple CRUD which can read/update other attributes of the customers.

Comment: If the schema of your data is fixed, then regular relational db gives your most flexibility fo queries and updates.

Comment: There's no such thing as "best" in engineering unless *you* define it. And then, how are you stuck deciding? Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design & all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: @philipxy, I believe I defined the problem. I didn't ask which is better without any constraints, assumptions or conditions. I precisely described the conditions, put numbers and the way the data is going to be used to define the problem as something closed. My goal was to ignore other possible factors and focus on these few ones I defined to make this question as precise as possible.
So I don't agree it's the kind of question you linked to.
I understand I may need to try both approaches but initial design can often be chosen without trials - it's impossible to always try all approaches.

Comment: @Marcin the schema is indeed fixed so it's a good point relational db gives more flexibility here. However, I wanted to focus on the presented use cases, assuming there is no more data usage outside these processes to limit the factors for this discussion. I will take into account the other factors but here I wanted to compare this simplified version.

Comment: Your comment doesn't address the issues in my comment. This question is too vague & general, also unresearched. Good luck.

Comment: Well, let's just agree to disagree here. Anyway, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I think people are overly afraid of DynamoDB scan operations. They're bad if used for regular queries but for once-in-a-while bulk operations they're not so bad.

How much does it cost to scan a 100 MB table? That's 25,000 4KB blocks. If doing eventually consistent that's 12,250 read units. If we assume the cost is $0.25 per million (On Demand mode) that's 12,250/1,000,000*$0.25 = $0.003 per full table scan. Want to do it 30 times per day? Costs you less than a dime a day.

The thing to consider is the cost of updating every item in the database. That's 500,000 write units, which if in On Demand at $1.25 per million will be about $0.63 per full table update.

If you can go Provisioned for that duration it'll be cheaper.

Regarding performance, DynamoDB can scan a full table faster than any server-oriented database, because it's supported by potentially thousands of back-end servers operating in parallel. For example, you can do a parallel scan with up to a million segments, each with a client thread reading data in 1 MB chunks. If you write a single-threaded client doing a scan it won't be as fast. It's definitely possible to scan slowly, but it's also possible to scan at speeds that seem ludicrous.

If your table is 100 MB, was created in On Demand mode, has never hit a high water mark to auto-increase capacity (just the starter capacity), and you use a multi-threaded pull with 4+ segments, I predict you'll be done in low single digit seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. My costs estimation gave me similar values to your ones. So I mean the costs should not be a problem here. The problem can be related to the performance and that's what I wanted to analyze. I may need to try both approaches and compare their performance but wanted to double check if it isn't something clear that the one approach will be obviously worse than the another one in terms of performance.

Comment: DynamoDB can scan a full table faster than any server-oriented database, because it's supported by potentially thousands of back-end servers operating in parallel. For example, you can do a parallel scan with up to a million segments, each with a client thread reading data in 1 MB chunks. If you write a single-threaded client doing a scan it won't be as fast. It's definitely possible to scan slowly, but it's also possible to scan at speeds that seem ludicrous.

Comment: If your table is 100 MB, was created in On Demand mode, has never hit a high water mark to auto-increase capacity (just the starter capacity), and you use a multi-threaded pull with 4+ segments, I predict you'll be done in low single digit seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the kind of information I was looking for. So I'm going to give it a try but it looks really promising.
Please add this information related to performance to your answer. I'm going to accept it.